# JRE 7 update 51 breaks java swing application; get error: access denied ("java.io.SerializablePermission" "enableSubclassImplementation")

Tags: java, weblogic

After installing JRE 7 update 51, our java swing applications doesn't work.
We have added the now required [manifest attributes](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias), so the application updates fine through java web start, and starts up, but it fails right after the log on process with the exception:

```
[CORBA MARSHAL 1398079699 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 211 completed: Maybe]
Caused by: access denied ("java.io.SerializablePermission" "enableSubclassImplementation")
```

If we use JRE 7 update 45 (or earlier versions) this error doesn't occur.

We're using Weblogic 9.2.3 as application server.

Any suggestions for solving this?

Edit: The jar files are signed with VeriSign Class 3 Code Signing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually quite simple.

The clients needed to add the following in their {java.home}\lib\security\java.policy file:

```
grant codeBase "https://mydomain.com:443" {
        permission java.io.SerializablePermission "enableSubclassImplementation"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's really the probelm, but in addition to the manifest attributes your application has to be signed now ([New security requirements for RIAs in 7u51](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias)).

Comment: We have always signed the jar files. :)